# Which xamarin android apk to publish on google store?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play

Xamarin has option for android as below

[image]

And I enabled it. After doing an archive and sign it ready for publish to google store, I thought I can upload multiple apks for same release and I have separate apks for each cpu as shown below. as well as I have 1 common including all.

[image]

But I cant figure out any option to upload armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86 apks separately. Can anybody lead me here? or it is not possible at all. It is my first publish that's why I used Alpha publish. Could it be the reason maybe?

Comment: Single APK can have multiple native libs for different ABIs. You should not have to make separate APK for each ABI.

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes I know. as I wrote in the question single one including all abis is also there and for now this is how I published but I read on xamarin documentation, it says that I can publish each separately, by that I gain advantage of size. because single apks are smaller than single apk. thats the purpose of my question

Comment: yes, you actually can do that (upload multiple APK). But it is quite complex. So you should limit CPU ABI of each APK through Manifest. This way Google Play will know which devices should get which APKs. Also you have to use different `versionCode` value for each APK since you can't upload 2 APKs with same varsionCode and package name